# ListIterator repeating elements on alternate calls of next() and previous()

Tags: java, collections, iterator, listiterator

I wrote the below programm to iterate in the list, but on alternate traversal `next() and previous()` it is repeating the element. I know the fix by putting an indicator and making use of it for `extra next` and `extra previous` prior to my printing logic. But i want to know why is the behaviour is like this and what is the algorithm behind the working of iterator.

I checked the javaDoc already and there its written like,

> **next**
>   Returns the next element in the list. This method may be called
>   repeatedly to iterate through the list, or intermixed with calls to
>   previous to go back and forth. **(Note that alternating calls to next
>   and previous will return the same element repeatedly.)**

but the question is why? and what is the logic or purpose behind doing so?

```
public class IterateLinkedListUsingListIterator {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {
    LinkedList lList = new LinkedList();

    lList.add("1");
    lList.add("2");
    lList.add("3");
    lList.add("4");
    lList.add("5");

    ListIterator itr = lList.listIterator();
    boolean ch = true;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (ch) {
        System.out.println("Enter choice");
        int chi = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        switch (chi) {
        case 1:
            if (itr.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(itr.next());
            }
            break;
        case 2:

            if (itr.hasPrevious()) {
                System.out.println(itr.previous());
            }
            break;

        default:
            ch = false;
        }

    }

}

}
```

as per @vincrichaud answer and **java doc** statement cursor points in between the element not on the element, Why is that so? is there any specific reason for it.

```
                     Element(0)   Element(1)   Element(2)   ... Element(n-1)
cursor positions:  ^            ^            ^            ^                  ^
```

Comment: It’s a reasonable question. ListIterators are a bit odd and hardly ever used. The way to understand them is to think of the current position as being between two elements. When you call next() you step over the element to your right (and return it). When you can previous() you step over the element to your left (and return it). It may seem bizarre but that’s just how it is.

Comment: It’s like repeatedly jumping left and right over the same object. The object you’re jumping over never changes. If you want the object jumped over to change you have to jump twice in the same direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

> **Next** Returns the next element in the list and advances the cursor position.
>
> **Previous** Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards.

What is not obvious is that the cursor position is always between element and not on element. It's also described in the doc.

> A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element

So knowing this, that's pretty obvious that when you call alternatively `next()` and `previous()` you will obtain the same element.

```
LinkedList lList = new LinkedList();
lList.add("1");
lList.add("2");
lList.add("3");
lList.add("4");
lList.add("5");
//lList look like [1,2,3,4,5]
ListIterator itr = lList.listIterator(); //create iterator at position before element 0

itr.next() // return the next element => so return "1"
           // And advance the cursor position => position between element 0 and element 1

itr.previous(); // return the previous element => so return "1"
           // And step back the cursor position => position before element 0
```

Comment: Ok so as per your answer the behaviour is fine now but why the cursor is placed in between the elements not on the elements.

Comment: I have no idea. Ask Oracle. I think it's because it's more "logical" to do act like that. The cursor indicates what element you have already gone through and which are not. Otherwise the element pointed will be neither already seen nor not seen yet. Also if pointing element function such as `next` and `previous` should be `getElementAndMoveForward` and `getElementAndMoveBackward` which I think is less user Friendly